# Can't form a Moq test to spoof context access

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Completely new to Moq and mock testing in general. I'm trying to follow a tutorial but fit it to my needs, which is spoofing some database access through entityFrameworkCore contexts. How do I setup and test the response for my database returning either a 0 or an arbitrary number?

To clarify, I want to test that providing "Whatever" to my DoSomething method will return a 0 and also that providing any other string will produce an entry Id. Of course the Id is dependent on database increments in real life, so I need to just set an arbitrary number as a response and test that this is returned. This is a very minified example of my real method, of course.

I've minimised the setup as much as possible:

Interface:

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    int DoSomething(string thing);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    private readonly TestContext _testContext;
    public TestClass(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
    }
    public int DoSomething(string thing)
    {
        if (thing == "Whatever") return 0;
        Item i = new Item()
        {
            Thing = thing
        };
        _testContext.Add(i);
        _testContext.SaveChanges();
        return i.Id;
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

Table / model class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Thing { get; set; }
}
```

I've ignored connection strings because the whole point is to test the method without connecting to a database, right? And finally here's my attempt at mocking which I'm completely clueless about, tbh:

```
    public void Test1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ITestClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething("Whatever"));
        // Assert returns 0
        mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething("ValidString"));
        // Assert returns arbitrary 12345 - where do I spoof this number?
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? TestClass constructor should have `ITestContext` as parameter to start with.

Comment: You need to create an object of TestClass in `Test1` by passing mock object to the constructor and the call Something method on it. An then assert the result. That's how you write unit tests.

Comment: Some clarification is needed about what is ***actually*** trying to be done. if `TestClass` is the subject under test, then it should not be mocked. As for the context, An in-memory database can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how mocking is used. Lets look at your test

```
public void Test1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ITestClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething("Whatever"));
        // Assert returns 0
        mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething("ValidString"));
        // Assert returns arbitrary 12345 - where do I spoof this number?
    }
```

Now when you use Setup on a mock, you are also to use Returns, ReturnsAsync, or Throws to tell the mock what you want it to return when you provide these values. So your setup for DoSomething should look like this

```
mock.Setup(m => m.DoSomething(It.Is<string>(i => i == "ValidString"))).Returns(12345);
```

But there should be an obvious problem here. If we are explicitly telling it exactly what to give us for a given input, then what are we really testing? Just the mock itself at that point. This isn't how mocks are intended to be used. So a rule, never mock the thing you are testing. Instead you mock its *dependencies*. In this case, the only one is the TestContext. Instead, we actually want to test the DoSomething method, so we create a real instance of that class to test.

You didn't specify which testing framework you are using, so I wrote mine with NUnit

```
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Mock the dependency
            Mock<ITestContext> mockContext = new Mock<ITestContext>();
            mockContext.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Item>()))
                .Returns(true);
            mockContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges())
                .Returns(true);

            // Inject the dependency
            TestClass testClass = new TestClass(mockContext.Object);

            int result = testClass.DoSomething("Whatever");

            // Verify the methods on the mock were called once
            mockContext.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Item>()), Times.Once);
            mockContext.Verify(m => m.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);

            // Assert that the result of the operation is the expected result defined elsewhere
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(ExpectedResult));
        }
```

Testing that a mock returns what you set it up to return offers no value. We want to test the real deal, mocking just makes that possible when the dependencies are complex. They are a stand-in the for backend systems and complex object graphs that the real system uses in practice and nothing more. The magic is that it allows us to only set up the parts of the mock that we need, the specific function calls and property access that the class which is dependent on it relies, without having to worry about setting up the entire class and all of its dependencies and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the comphrehensive answer. You're right, I wasn't sure what I was even asking, I basically wanted to test my methods and make sure they returned the correct Auto-incremented ID's but without hooking up to an actual SQL database. I ended up using entityFrameworkCore's SQL `InMemory` to set up a dataset as if it were pulled from SQL so the methods should return the same ID's each time they're tested. No `Moq` required!